# Facebook auth / request userid

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to develop a new FB App, however it seems they have changed their ways once again.
Im looking for the correct way to authenticate a fb user to my app, and retrieve the userid.

I have found the following method:

```
// Authenticate the user
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
}

if(empty($code) && !isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' 
  . 'client_id=' . $app_id
  . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($app_url)
  . '&state=' . $_SESSION['state']
  . '&scope=publish_actions';

print('');
exit;
```

My question is now.
Do i not need the facebook SDK at all ? Since its not needed here im thinking its not needed at all.
Would the correct way be to put this code in top of all my documents, thereby constantly making sure the user is authorized ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

It will require something like this:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<YOUR_APP_ID>";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Not quite sure how I should use that function though

Comment: with the linked stuff you can check the status of your visitor. put it in some js-script which is processed after the pageloading. (i.e. onLoad() of body)
The other stuff put just before the body-closing tag of the html-file

Comment: I tried the following after calling FB.Init (and added alert to each state), but im not getting any script errors or notification from Alert, so i suspect im missing something: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: have you connected it with a valid app-id? I just put three asterisks where you have to insert the appId.

Comment: Im simply using the script from the link, that should determine the login status, and of course including: connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js before the <script>

Comment: I recently used that both scripts in combination and it works very well. Have you added the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` ?

Comment: I found the error. Specifying channelurl to FB.Init was needed. Now it will detect the login.
I'm trying the technique of saving $user_id in a session, after login, and the cross checking with JS if the actual user_id is equal to the session.
Not sure its a good technique, but that way i can pass a user to a new login if the session does not match.
Thank you again for the help

Comment: Though i do have another question you might be able to answer.
Is there a way to detect if the app is open in the facebook frame, so that i can avoid people using the app "outside" facebook?

Comment: You should not be starting a venture with Facebook Connect. It is being phased out.

Comment: Is there another technique that you would suggest or recommend ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, my answer lays that out :)

Comment: Yes, but i will still need to use setAutoGrow, in order to set the size of the facebook frame. As far as i know connect is the only way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Correct there is no longer a need for the SDK. Facebook is trying to get developers to use their Graph API which is why they no longer support all their old junk code, and why FBML is going to stop working in June, etc.

Use this page to wrap your head around the new API: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

There is no "correct way". You can do whatever you need to do to meet your site needs, if that means setting a token cookie and caching an auth request for 20 minutes instead of forcing the user to check the token on Facebook's end every request, that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks that helped alot. So incredibly hard to find answers in this world ;)
Do you know if there is a way to check if the user is still "inside" the facebook frame. 
I'm trying to avoid users opening new frames that will show the app outside the facebook frame.

Comment: Sorry that's not possible since Facebook is on a different domain. You'd normally use `top.location.href` for same-domain parent window URL access.